# New emails only on Imap and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, imap

I'm working on a system that downloads the emails into a database, however I want to grab only the new emails from the inbox.

At this moment I have this procedure:

```
//find new emails
$news = imap_search($conn, 'SINCE "4 February 2014"');
```

However I believe that tracking by date is really not a good practice, and I want to replace that for a query that allows me to grab only the emails with the **Msgno** bigger than the last one I have.

Is there any way to make **imap_search()** or any other function to select only the emails with a Msgno bigger than the one specified?

Comment: Reading suggestion: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4

Comment: Dankeshön bro! seems like UID would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:

```
$count = imap_num_msg($connection);
for($msgno = 1; $msgno <= $count; $msgno++) {
$headers = imap_headerinfo($connection, $msgno);
if($headers->Unseen == 'U') {
... do something ...
}
}
```

Comment: This assumes there are no other IMAP clients using the account.

Comment: Yes, I removed the "if($headers->Unseen == 'U') {" line... I take the last one from the database, and then I start a for loop from the last one on db to the last one on imap. (downloading each one in between both limits)

Comment: @ChrisRusso: you grab it from .. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-unread-messages/

Comment: @ChrisRusso. You must mention source link whenever grabbing like this.

Comment: Thanks bro! in any case is useless! Ps: 1 week ago I was in Banjara Hills, Hyderabad, nice place bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally solve this doing the following procedure:

1. Select the last MSGNO you got in the IMAP (using **imap_num_msg()** )
2. Select the last MSGNO you got in the DB.
3. Now, we only have to loop using a For between the last one on DB and the last one on IMAP.

Download everysingle email in the middle and store it into the database.

//calculamos el máximo
        $maximo = imap_num_msg($conn);

```
    //comenzamos desde... (from db)
    $msgno = 1

    //recorremos los mails
    for($msgno <= $maximo; $msgno++) {

        //sacamos la información del email especificado
        $email['header']    = imap_headerinfo( $conn, $nuevo );
        $email['body']      = imap_fetchbody ( $conn, $nuevo, 1);

        $emails[] = $email;
    }
```

**Kind regards!**

Comment: Yes, but you should use UIDs, not message sequence numbers.  If a message is deleted, message sequence numbers *decrease*, but UIDs do not.